# What is the "Processing role?"

Tags: xconnect, configuration, upgrade, server-role

I'm patching form Sitecore 10.2.0 to 10.2.2, and in documentation it has the following line:

### Updating `Web.config` on `ContentManagement/ContentDelivery/Processing` roles

I know what CM and CD are, but I'm less familiar with this "Processing" role. I know xConnect has a "processing engine" Windows service located in the `\App_Data\jobs\continuous\ProcessingEngine` folder, but it has no `web.config`. Any idea where this `web.config` for the Processing role is located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The processing is one of the Server roles used for Extracting information from captured, raw analytics data and transforming it into a form suitable for use in reporting applications.

Rule-based configuration allows you to quickly set up a role without having to manually enable and disable individual configuration files. Rule-based configuration values are set in the web.config file.

You can specify single or combined role using web.config.

```
<add key="role:define" value="ContentManagement" />
```

Combining roles

```
<add key="role:define" value="Processing,Reporting" />
```

So check your environment find the processing role and then apply the `web.config` changes to it.

Reference: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/platform-administration-and-architecture/rule-based-configuration.html

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on the scaling environment, here are the details that you are looking for.

In order to start scaling and optimizing your Sitecore installation, you must move the separate server roles to their own instances. You must then specify which server role each instance performs.

To specify the server role:

In the `web.config` file, in the `<AppSettings>` section, specify the server role value:

```
<AppSettings>
<add key="role:define" value="[server role]"/>
</AppSettings>
```

The supported values for the server role are:

- ContentDelivery
- ContentManagement
- Processing
- Reporting
- Standalone

So when you download the `Sitecore 10.2.0 rev. 006766 (WDP XPScaled packages)` package and extract the processing role, you will find the `web.config` in the website content folder.

Refer to [this](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/platform-administration-and-architecture/define-the-server-role.html) doc for more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is it normal to not have a separate Processing role, but you have separate CD and CM roles?